# android pass view to async task

Tags: android, button, asynchronous, view, task

I tried to add button dinamically inside async task (i've choose to send view and context to async task constructor) but not works.
can you help me?

here is the code:
on create void i have this

```
View content = getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT);
GetTokenRequest getToken = new GetTokenRequest(this.getApplicationContext(),content );
String[] params = new String[]{"","","http://"};
getToken.execute(params);
```

then i've create async task:

```
      public static final class GetTokenRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
          private Context context;
          private View view;
            public GetTokenRequest(Context ctx, View vw) {
                context = ctx;
                view=vw;


            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String Username = params[0];
                String PassWord = params[1];
                String URL = params[2];

                String data = sendHttpPostRequest(Username, PassWord,URL);
                return data;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if (result !=null){


                      try {

                          JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                          // Getting JSON Array node
                          TokenList = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_tokenlist);
                       // looping through All Contacts
                          for (int i = 0; i < TokenList.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = TokenList.getJSONObject(i);
                            String deviceporttoken = c.getString("a");
                             String PortName = c.getString("b");
                              String IMageUrl = c.getString("c");

                              ImageButton imgToken=new ImageButton(context);
                              final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsimgToken = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                              paramsimgToken.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
                              paramsimgToken.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                              paramsimgToken.width=100;
                              paramsimgToken.width=50;



                              imgToken.setId(i);
                              imgToken.setLayoutParams(paramsimgToken);

                              imgToken.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                                        }

                                    });

                            View rootView = ((Activity)context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                              linearLayout1= (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
                              linearLayout1.addView(imgToken);


                          }

                      } catch (JSONException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                            }                   
                //parsing json
            }

      }}
```

the problem is that `linearLayout1.addView(imgToken);` get `null point exception`.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Can we see the xml where "content" and "linearLayout1" are defined?

Comment: it's because you don't assign any value to it, you don't initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your AsyncTask an inner class?

Because, if you write the AsyncTask class as **inner class** of your activity, you can easily acces the views of you activity in onPostExecute.

Just declare your LinearLayout as global value of the activity, call 'findById' in the onCreate of your activity and you're good to go.

Now in the onPostExecute, just call myLinearLayout.addView

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: yes, i declared  LinearLayout as global value of the activity, called 'findById' in the onCreate of activity and it works! Thank you